# Efficiently bind objects on grid

Tags: algorithm, binding, grid, subset, subset-sum

Given a nXn matrix. And given some objects of various shapes/sizes as given below. How can I efficiently bind all the objects on the grid?

Shapes are as given in this image:

[image]

"bind" means arranging the objects on nXn grid. An object can have size 1,2,... First 7 size shapes are shown in the image.

Comment: Could you define how do you "bind" objects and what do you consider to be an effective binding? What kind of object do you have? Could explain what does the picture say exactly? You question is a bit unclear.

Comment: "bind" means arranging the objects on nXn grid. Let's leave effecting binding as of now. The "objects" are as shown in image. An object can have size 1,2,... First 7 size shapes are shown in the image.

Comment: How do you determine wan effective binding?

Comment: effective binding => better time complexity

Comment: Then I can put the pieces anywhere I want on the board. Aren't there any restrictions? What's the purpose of the shapes's numbers then? If you have taken this problem from textbook or website could refer to it ?

Comment: If you start putting objects randomly then you might not be able to place all objects. Consider two objects having (n/2)*(n/2) grid shape. And now if you place one of this in middle then you might now be able to place the other object. But if you place your first object starting from your first row and first column then you can easily place the second object.

Comment: So your shapes are not necessarily 1x1. I see. But do they always have to have rectangular shape?

Comment: You can see some of the shapes as given in the picture above. For eg the third shape in the image is L-shaped. So object can be of any shape.